# why email sent using PHPMailer + tls has To address hidden

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, tls1.2

I am using PHPMailer to send emails via SMTP with TLS encryption. Emails were sending fine and received as expected. But for some reason, the To address of each email is not shown. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
  $mailer = new PHPMailer;

  // header
  $mailer->IsHTML(true);
  $mailer->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
  $mailer->WordWrap = 80;

  // protocol
  $mailer->isSMTP();                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mailer->SMTPDebug = 0;
  $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;               // Enable SMTP authentication

  // credential
  $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            // Enable encryption
  $mailer->Host = $agent['host'];         
  $mailer->Port = $agent['port'];
  $mailer->Username = $agent['username']; // SMTP username
  $mailer->Password = $agent['password']; // SMTP password

  // setup different addresses
  $mailer->From = $agent['from'];
  $mailer->FromName = $agent['from_name'];
  $mailer->addAddress($to, $name);
  $mailer->addBCC($agent['bcc']);
  $mailer->SingleTo = true;                

  // content
  $mailer->Subject = $subject;
  $mailer->Body = $html; 
  $mailer->AltBody = $text;                

  // finally, send out the mail message
  if (!$mailer->Send()) {
    throw new Exception('[Mailer] error: ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo);
  }

  // clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
  $mailer->clearAddresses();
```

Comment: are value of $to and $agent['bcc'] same ?

Comment: no, not the same. in my current setting, bcc is the same as from address. just for the purpose of keeping a copy to myself.

Comment: can you give me the value which you are setting in $to.

Comment: the $to could be any email address, tried a few different ones, all the same behavior

Comment: Don't do this: `$mailer->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";`, just do `$mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`. You've based your code on an obsolete example - look at [current ones](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples). It would help if you [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki). Also, `SingleTo` doesn't work with SMTP.